# How to get PWA desktop application hardware close button click event?

Tags: angularjs, service-worker, desktop-application, progressive-web-apps

I have created Progressive-web-app for Desktop, i want to get close event of hardware close button, it is possible to get.

> while closing app from windows default close button *(near to Restore
>   down and Minimize - top right corner)*, i want to call logout function.

Comment: closing entire application using windows default close button, i want to call some functions @jess.

Comment: What do you want to close? Some part of your application, or the entire desktop browser tab?

Comment: not like that, while closing app from windows default close button (near to Restore down and Minimize - top right corner), i want to call logout function, any way to trigger @Mathias